# Angular Foundation Error

Tags: angular, typescript, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make Jquery and Foundation to work for me. But it is not working.I want to use the modal from Foundation. I have added the Jquery in angular-cli.json. I have search all over the internet but no answer with angular and Jquery

This is the error I am getting.

```
AddEditInvoiceComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function
at AddEditInvoiceComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/invoice/add-edit-invoice/add-edit-invoice.component.ts.AddEditInvoiceComponent.ngAfterViewChecked (add-edit-invoice.component.ts:40)
at callProviderLifecycles (core.es5.js:11179)
at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.es5.js:11147)
at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.es5.js:11131)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12259)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12557)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12252)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12531)
```

My Component

```
    import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-invoice',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-invoice.component.css']
})
export class AddEditInvoiceComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  finalTotal: number;
  finalTax: number;
  productListSum: CustomPurchaseOrderProduct[];
  customerListSum;
  employeeListSum;


  constructor(
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private purchaseOrderService: PurchaseOrderService,
              private invoiceService: InvoiceService,
              private customerService: CustomerService
        ) { }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    $(document).foundation();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.buildForm();
    this.getAllCustomers();
    this.getAllEmployees();
    this.getAllProductsSumList();
  }
```

My Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NewFront</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation-float.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```